# Hidden Bottom Navigation View regardless of appearing in the xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar

**Summary**

I try to make Bottom Navigation View with Java and android studio.

However, it disappears the bar regardless of showing exact screen in the xml file.

**Goal**

I'd like to show BottomNavigationView like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chso6xrJ6aU).

Goal screen is below picture.

[image: Goal]

**Issue**

I am coding the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chso6xrJ6aU), and done. The xml file is exact screen layout,
but when I build the screen, I saw different layout.

[image: Error]

**What I try**
Compared to the code, almost all code isn't different.

Also turn off the fragment code, it works.

I guess the reason why it is disappear must be layout.

However, when I change the number of width or height, it shows same screen.

What's more, when I use layout construction such as Linerlayout, it shows same screen.

**Code**

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".home">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomnavi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="673dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomnavi"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` parameter of the `fragment` to `0dp` unless you want it for some reason.

Change these parameters of the `<fragment`:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Change/Add these parameters of your `<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment2"
```

And see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for apply. Fix it and show same phenomenon.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  I try to clear project, but same

Comment: @AkiraKusama I edited my answer check it out.

Comment: Sorry to ask you many times. I checked them. Also I see no tab bar. Actually the screen is full view which fragment shows.

Comment: @AkiraKusama ok just to be sure change the `<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`'s `layout_height` to something visible like `android:layout_height="150dp"` and see the outcome and tell me.